# AWS code build restore error NU1100: Unable to resolve for .Net core 3.1

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, continuous-integration, aws-codebuild

I have a pipeline on AWS for my api service which written in .Net core 3.1.

My buildspec.yml pretty simple, it runs `dotnet restore` and `dotnet publish`.

I get this error in the restore phase "error NU1100: Unable to resolve" for a lot of libraries,
for example:

> C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src363055303\src\ExternalClient\ExternalClient.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Serilog (>= 2.9.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'.

I tried to restore the project on my pc through the terminal using the same command and it works.

I see in the log that the pipeline use nuget org: "Feeds used: [https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"](https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json%22).

This pipeline already worked on AWS, and I have no idea why it started to fail over restore.

Comment: I'm seeing this error transiently.  Did you ever find a fix?

Comment: And which Environment Image were you using?  Windows?

Comment: I am seeing this error transiently as well. One day the build worked, the next it failed. I moved "dotnet restore" into the "build" part of the pipeline (it was in pre_build) and it suddenly started working. I am unsure if it suddenly started working because this fixed the error or there was another problem in the AWS infrastructure which suddenly fixed itself.

Comment: I see the same error, it's a Windows 10 machine https://i.imgur.com/A6YGlhI.png

Comment: sorry for the late response, the issue was the ec2 template.
I was using latest and it suddenly broke.
I switch back to an older version which worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with AWS Support, the issue was the Ec2 image.
I was using latest and they suggested that its not the best practise to always use latest.
I switched to an older image version and the build is working again.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install a few things because the machine probably doesn't have VS installed.

Examples bellow use Chocolatey to install things

Nuget

```
choco install nuget.commandline
```

MSBuild (in my case I'm using the latest because I'm running on dotnet core 5

```
choco install visualstudio2019buildtools
```

Add source to nuget

```
dotnet nuget add source --name nuget.org https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

Configure `MSBuildSDKsPath` environment variable to point to the dotnet sdk ex: `'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.202\Sdks\'`

After these steps `dotnet restore` worked without any issues.